# NodeJS app keep saying request timed out on azure web app

Tags: node.js

Deployed a simple NodeJS app to Azure web app but keep getting 'request timed out' error.
The app is running on NodeJS platform. If I visit "https://XXXX.azurewebsites.net/" I see that there is a default site running at port 80 which displays the below.

[image]

Here is my app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello. Welcome to this blog')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

then I ran the app using node app.js.
I tested with postman using GET "https://XXXX.azurewebsites.net:3000" and get timed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After speaking with Microsoft Support, the only way that worked was the below documentation. They still couldn't answer why my simple node code wont work. Anyway, this is what worked. Use VSCode to create the sample project from the documentation. Then use an FTP client, use the credentials provided on your webapp settings. Upload the files to azure web app. Remember to restart your app and wait for about 5-10 mins. And, it worked.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=linux&pivots=development-environment-azure-portal

Comment: So you’re uploading your files using FTP. Did you at any point in time create a build of your App?

Comment: yes, I created the azure webapp first (xxx.azurewebsites.net) and go to the deployment center to get your FTP credentials.

Comment: The only issue with deploying like this is when the code base grows, it'll be difficult to upload all the files but I guess this should do for smaller applications.

Comment: @SebastianGbudje Git pipeline is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line of code below:

```
const port = 3000
```

As it currently stands, you are always listening on port 3000 which isn't what Azure is working off (it's usually port 80 unless otherwise specified). So you are basically sending requests to the wrong port. In order to fix this, you need to change that above line to the below

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
```

What that does is it sets your `port` to 3000 if it cannot find the `port` from your environmental variable. Per [Azure Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux#get-port-number), App Service sets the environment variable PORT in the Node.js container, and forwards the incoming requests to your container at that port number.

The Next step would be to re-deploy your app and that should fix things. If you are dead set on using port 3000 you'll need to look into how to change your port to `3000` on Azure

**Note:**
I am not too familiar with Azure but you might also need to set the `env` in Azure to get it to work correctly i.e you might need to go add the `PORT` and it's value in Azure's environmental variables page. But I highly doubt you'll need to

Comment: It is trying to use 8080 but fails with a display saying 'address already in use'

Comment: In your `package.json` are you starting your app using `build:azure`? if so, change it to `start`